# Delete the parent container of a cloned element (jQuery)

Tags: jquery

What I have so far is the ability to clone an HTML element to another HTML element.  The HTML being cloned has a delete link (class .delete-inquiry) that should allow the user to remove the newly cloned HTML element.

With the click on a link, I would like to delete this whole cloned element but not other elements that have the same class (only delete the one that contains the link).

```
     $(".delete-inquiry").click(function(){
        $('this').parents('inquiry-content').remove();
     });
```

HTML:

[image]

The whole item in .inquiry-content gets copied and then places into the added-inquiry DIV.  Therefore we can have multiple items with same structure on the page simultaneously.  Each of those items has its own delete link that should only delete the corresponding item (the .inquery-content that it lives on).

Please help me out.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.inquiry-content').remove();` but that's not clear what is the cloned element and posting an image for HTML markup isn't that a great idea...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `''` from `this` context and add `.` before the class selector

```
$('.added-inquiry,.inquiry').on('click','.delete-inquiry',function(){
//-- Use event delegation since some of them are dynamically generated
    $(this).parents('.inquiry-content').remove();
    //-^-------------^------------------
});
```

Comment: Thank you Pranav C Balan, this worked perfectly. I will mark yours as correct since you were the first to answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".delete-inquiry").click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.inquiry-content').remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".added-inquiry").on("click",".delete-inquiry", function(){
    $(this).parents(".inquiry-content").remove();
});
```